# Can command jobs with a box have start_times?

Tags: autosys

I would like to have 3 commands that run at 3 different times in the same day.

I want to create 1 top-level box that will contain these 3 commands. And set a different Start_time value for each of them... Instead of creating 3 top-level boxes with command job in each & setting Start_time on top level box.

can this be done?

i tried setting the START_TIMES: 11:00 TIME_ZONE: NewYork in each command job, but when I uploaded Jil file, and did autorep -j Job_name -q, the start_times and time_zone property that I set has been removed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that as long as the top level box doesn't have a date/time condition. Bad things can happen when the box and the jobs in a box both have date/time conditions, like jobs not running when expected. This may not happen if you are using the look back conditions in Autosys R11, but I don't have experience in R11 using look back conditions.

Why do you want to group them in a box for? Remember a box is for jobs with like starting conditions. If they have different start times, they have different starting conditions. If they for example start on the success of job_a AND start_times: hh:mm, then you can have box_b start on s(job_a) then the jobs in the box start on start_times: hh:mm.

Not sure why your start_times: and time_zone: commands are not taking. Are you getting any error messages when you run the jil command?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I removed the date/time conditions from the box properties and left them on each command, sometimes I am seeing them run at the specified time..but other.. i am seeing the command jobs run as soon as the top box is activated. some conditions of the command job include:                    date_conditions: 1
days_of_week: mo,tu,we,th,fr
start_times: "23:00"    ..dont think I am doing anything wronf here?  but yea, it makes sense not to have them in the same box.thanks

Comment: Force_starting a top level box, can make jobs ignore time/date conditions